# Not able to open 'gvim' on RHEL7

Tags: vim, rhel7

While running gvim on RHEL machine, I get the  message

```
E233: cannot open display
```

Please let me know how to fix the issue ?

Comment: This is probably not the right place nor the right way to ask for this, but you should check if your DISPLAY environment variable is set properly.

Comment: Did you try this under X Windows or just console? You cannot run GUI programs from a non-X console.

Comment: I have set DISPLAY variable , it's' giving the same issue . Any further suggestions on this .

Comment: Do you mean to install xserver ?